# How can I perform on update cascade in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EF Database First:
 
I have model

```
public class Book {
  public Guid BookId { get;set; }
  public string BookName { get;set; }
  public string CategoryCode { get;set; } 
  public Category Category { get;set; }
}

public class Category {
  public Guid CategoryId { get;set; }
  public string CategoryName { get;set; }
  public string CategoryCode { get;set; }
}
```

Then, in my Context i have

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasKey(c => c.BookId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .Property(c => c.CategoryCode )
            .HasColumnName("Category");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Category)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoryCode )
            .HasPrincipalKey(bu => bu.CategoryCode );
```

When I try to update CategoryName the error :
The property 'CategoryName ' on entity type 'Category' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.

So I try to so On update cascade but I see only On delete cascade. So how can I update it?.

Actually I just try to refer 'CategoryCode' in Book to 'CategoryCode' in Category and able to update that so how it should be?

Comment: Using a *name* as a key is a bad idea. The Book should have a `Category` property, not a string with the `CategoryName`. Category's primary key should be its ID, not its name. Primary Keys shouldn't have any business functionality. It shouldn't change in response to normal business opearations. The category itself doesn't change if the name changes, in fact, editing names is a very common operation.

Comment: After the edit there's no need for cascading updates unless the `CategoryCode` is a business field to. If not, there's no reason to have both a `CategoryId` and a `CategoryCode`

Comment: CategoryCode is business field which can update by client and the database have design to be 'Book' and 'Category' to be corporate by CategoryCode which I can not change anything. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: @JanNutcha Even `CategoryCode` become a business field you dont need to relate it to ForeignKey. You can safely use `CategoryId` instead.

Comment: @JanNutcha does the database *really* have a foreign key constraint on `CategoryCode`? What's the point of including `CategoryId` then? You mentioned this is a Database First context. You should post the tables schema (ie `CREATE TABLE` statements along with any foreign keys, constraints etc.). I suspect the real relations are different

Comment: Yep it different it does not have foreign key constraint in Database. It have Book table and Category table doesn't related in the real database

Answer (score 0):

As @PanagiotisKanavos already explained greatly in the comment, I am just posting the solution:

`CategoryCode` is not the `PrimaryKey` of `Category` model class. So you can not make `CategoryCode` as `ForeignKey` in `Book` model class. Instead you have to use `CategoryId` as `ForeignKey` in `Book` model class as follows:

```
public class Book 
{
  public Guid BookId { get;set; }
  public string BookName { get;set; }

  [ForeignKey("Category")]
  public Guid CategoryId { get;set; } // <-- Here CategoryId instead of CategoryCode
  public Category Category { get;set; }
}
```